# How to query the data with selected date range in CloudBoost

Tags: node.js, mongodb, cloudboost

I want to fetch the records from the `CloudTable` with particular date range say from : `startDate` to `endDate`

Answer (score 0):

We can query all columns including DateTime type in a CloudTable. There are several condition you can add to your query like lessThan, greaterThan etc.
In this case, you can use the following query -

```
var query = new CB.CloudQuery("TableName");
query.lessThan('dateColumns',"15-12-2016");
query.greaterThan('dateColumns',"15-06-2017");
query.find({
  success: function(list) {
    //list is an array of CloudObjects
  },
  error: function(error) {
  }
});
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding :)